# Error: Provider not set or invalid

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask, nodejs

I'm not able to connect metamask with nodejs.

```
var Web3        = require('web3');
var web3        = new Web3();

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
// Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
 web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
 } else {
console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!');
  }
```

It is showing the error :

> Error: Provider not set or invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the second line of your code is wrong. Try to remove this:

```
var web3        = new Web3();
```

as per doc this is the right way to create an instance of web3

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}
```

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#adding-web3

Comment: I tried this one..Its going to the else part (ie;testrpc). All transactions are done and can be viewed in testrpc. I need to do transaction using metamask.

Comment: Metamask is injected to the client. I don't think you can get the provider inside the server side (NodeJS). That code will work well in your UI